# How can i import more than one component from the same folder?

Tags: reactjs, import, jsx

I have two files in my folder which i use. Minside.js and footer.js. 
When i import import Minside from "./component/Minside.js" to **index.js** it works as it should.
Now i want to import bottom.js to the MyApp.js as import bottom from "./component/footer.js". But the code editor wont find the keyword "bottom" like it does with "minSide". Those two files are in the exact same folder.

**//Minside.js file**

```
import React from "react";
import bottom from "./component/bottom.js"; // **This do not work**

function Minside() {
    return (
     <div>
<main>
<nav></nav>
</main>
<footer/>
     </div>
    )
}

export default Minside
```

**// index.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Minside from "./component/Minside.js" // **This works. I can import the minside component to index.js**

ReactDOM.render(<Minside />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**//Bottom.js file**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
function bottom() {

return (
)
<footer> <h1> This is my footer </h1>
}

export default bottom
```

Comment: Are you using the j programming language? If not, [edit] your question and remove the tag...

Answer (score 1):

Import from same location

```
 import bottom from "./bottom.js";
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205266/discussion-on-answer-by-alex-how-can-i-import-more-than-one-component-from-the-s).

Answer (score 0):

You need to capitalize your 'Bottom' component.

> 'When an element type starts with a lowercase letter, it refers to a
>   built-in component like  or  and results in a string 'div'
>   or 'span' passed to React.createElement. Types that start with a
>   capital letter like  compile to React.createElement(Foo) and
>   correspond to a component defined or imported in your JavaScript file.'
>   https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html